# Implementing servlet lifecycle methods in a Spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, tomcat, integration-testing

I am implementing a web application using Spring. I am using Spring's ContextLoaderListener, to load up my application contexts, and Spring's DispatcherServlet, to load the relevant beans from {name}-servlet.xml, which refer to the beans in the main application context. I want to be able to integration test these Spring configurations outside of the container to validate everything is wired up correctly before I deploy to Tomcat. However my application requires some scheduled background processing when running in the container. In a regular HttpServlet I would simply implement init() and destroy(). All the suggestions I have read suggest using an InitializingBean for that kind of initialization.

However, if I use an InitializingBean, afterPropertiesSet() gets called whether I am inside the container or in integration tests - and outside the container, I don't have access to the resources that background task needs. Is there a better way to perform the tasks I would normally perform in init() and destroy() so that they will only run when deployed as a webapp?

Comment: I thought perhaps I could use getServletContext() within the controller's InitializingBean afterPropertiesSet() method to determine whether I am running as a servlet or not. That throws an exception outside the container, so I can make the initialization steps conditional. It works, but it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a test spring config file that overrides the bean implementing your background process?

This way everything else in the spring configuration would work normally except for the one overridden bean.

Comment: I like this idea a lot. It fits well with the other things I am doing like including initializing beans to load test data into the DB, and it keeps the test specifics out of the code. Thanks!